# NUXT 3 - Refresh deletes Cookies

Tags: nuxt.js

Currently using Nuxt 3 to build a app.  I am able to create cookies for a token using:

```
// Within my /server/api endpoint
setCookie ( res, 'token', result.token, {  maxAge : 24 * 60 * 60});
```

The token is successfully created and visible within Chrome/ Inspection Window / Application / Cookies.  However, upon refresh, the token disappears.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I`m having the same issue using the useCookie() did you find any solution

Comment: Did you guys endup resolving this issue? i'm having the same issue with strapi 4 and nuxt 3. @LucasSchirm 

https://forum.strapi.io/t/strapi-nuxt3-cookie-gets-deleted-on-page-reload/35010

Comment: Not sure what this question is about in the first place tho. What is `setCookie` and how does it disappear? We have no [repro].